# Matplotlib stuck to load into conda env

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

[Installation Stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXb87.png)

The picture is showing the problem I am facing right now.
I am trying to add Matplotlib to one of my Conda Environments, but it is getting stuck at the installing stage. I did some research on this problem and I can't seem to find the answer. I did try to do the same thing with cmd, but not working either.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: "with cmd, but not working either" meaning?

Comment: @Eypros the command sequence to create env, activate, and install packages.

Comment: I mean do you get any error messages etc?

Comment: @Eypros nvm, I got it working, I just reinstalled Anaconda.....